# Print color render 20 x 30 inches

Tags: rendering

With Blender 3D, can I print a custom size color graphic of the model? I want to print 20 x 30 inches in high definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output for Print](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/output-for-print)?

Comment: @metaphor_set Yes, it would be.