# Help me understand render quality. How to get it high res…

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I wish to render some high res images to be used in large format/prints at a fair.

I am a beginner at specs and render knowöedge… and I cant understand how to get my renders to be crispy sharp and high res in Cycles? I want to be able to zoom in and see details.

Sample rate is most often mentioned as the way to go, but I only start to see sharp details when going up in **size** (like to 4K or 8K) - *not* in samples (?!).

Heres an example on a image. 1920 size and 8192 samples (!).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/trpDS.jpg

Comment: Resolution and samples are 2 different things, samples are how grainy the image is, resolution is the number of pixels, to get hi-res you need a high resolution, if it looks too grainy, increase the sample (but there are other tricks to avoid grains)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output for Print](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/output-for-print)